# Compose stream of effects for http response

Tags: scala, scala-cats, cats-effect, http4s, fs2

I want to make a streaming JSON response via HTTP. The purpose is to send current time in a given city every second.

**TL;DR: I need help with sending a result in effect `F` and a function, which returns this effect, should be called every 1 second. Is there a simple way you know of?**

I've already tried several approaches and all of them do not work.

1. This is the first one:

```scala
       def timeStreamingRoutes[F[_]: Sync : Timer](times: Times[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
         val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F]{}
         import dsl._
    
         HttpRoutes.of[F] {
           case GET -> Root / "streaming" / city =>
    
             val throttling = Stream.awakeEvery[F](1.second)
    
             for {
               timeOrErr <- times.get(city.toUpperCase)
               resp <- timeOrErr match {
                 case Right(time) => Ok(throttling.map(_ => time.asJson))
                 case Left(error) => BadRequest(throttling.map(_ => error.asJson))
               }
             } yield resp
         }
       }
```

Here, my `times.get(city.toUpperCase)` function has the following signature:

```scala
    def get(city: String): F[Either[Times.CurrentTimeError, Times.CurrentTime]]
```

, where `CurrentTimeError` and `CurrentTime` are my custom case classes.The problem is that I get time only once in `timeOrErr <- times.get(city.toUpperCase)` line. So, every second it sends absolutely identical value (like, 2:43:31, 2:43:31, etc. And I want it to be 2:43:31, 2:43:32, etc.). And I have no idea how to make this function being called every second.

2. Also, I tried to use a slightly different technique (and many others similar to this one):

```scala
       def timeStreamingRoutes[F[_]: Sync : Timer](times: Times[F]): HttpRoutes[F] = {
         val dsl = new Http4sDsl[F]{}
         import dsl._
    
         HttpRoutes.of[F] {
           case GET -> Root / "streaming" / city =>
    
             val throttling = Stream.awakeEvery[F](1.second)
             val payload    = Stream(
               for {
                 timeOrErr <- times.get(city.toUpperCase)
                 resp      <- timeOrErr match {
                   case Right(time) => Ok(time.asJson)
                   case Left(error) => BadRequest(error.asJson)
                 }
               } yield resp
             )
    
             val stream = throttling.zipRight(payload)
    
             Ok(stream)
         }
       }
```

The problem here is the hell with nested monads. `stream` has the `Stream[F, F[Response[F]]]` type. And I can't make it a proper `F[Response[F]]` because fs2 Stream does not provide functions like `sequence` or `traverse`. If I try to return `Ok(stream)`, then Circe cannot serialize `F` because it's abstract, so it is not even compiled.

3. The 3rd approach is:

```scala
       HttpRoutes.of[F] {
         case GET -> Root / "streaming" / city =>
    
           val throttling = Stream.awakeEvery[F](1.second)
           val payload    = Stream(
             for {
               timeOrErr <- times.get(city.toUpperCase)
               resp      <- timeOrErr match {
                 case Right(time) => time.asJson
                 case Left(error) => error.asJson
               }
             } yield resp
           )
    
           val stream = throttling.map(_ => payload)
            
           Ok(stream)
       }
```

Well, number 3 is not compiled either. Primarily because I can't compose monads in `payload`. That is, `case Right(time) => time.asJson` and `case Left(error) => error.asJson` must be something like  `case Right(time) => SomethingThatcanBeUsedAsALastWrapperInThisForComprehension(time.asJson)`.

Unfortunately, official [docs](https://http4s.org/v0.20/streaming/) has little info about it. I'll be glad to hear any suggestions!

Comment: I'm not familiar with fs2 but I would expect a `mapAsync` method that you can use like `throttling.mapAsync(times.get(city.toUpperCase))`. It's just the global idea, obviously with generic effect types, this is not so easy.

Comment: The key here is to run the effect for each element of the stream instead of running the effect once and use its value for each element of the stream.

Comment: @GaëlJ thanks for the response! I'll try to look into `mapAsync`. By the way, do you think I should replace abstract `F` with the concrete `IO` from Cats? Because `F` is what's left from the http4s auto-skeleton. I was confused about whether it should be replaced with a concrete effect type in this function.

Comment: If you're not building some kind of library, just set a concrete type yes !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For what I could understand you want something like this:

```scala
import cats.effect.{ContextShift, IO, Timer}
import fs2.Stream
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.semiauto.deriveEncoder
import org.http4s.{EntityEncoder, HttpRoutes}
import org.http4s.circe.streamJsonArrayEncoderOf
import org.http4s.dsl.Http4sDsl

import scala.concurrent.duration._ // Provides the second extension method.

type Error = String
final case class Time(data: Long)

trait Times {
  def get(cityName: String): IO[Either[Error, Time]]
}

object MyService extends Http4sDsl[IO] {
  // JSON Encoders.
  private implicit final val CirceEncoder: Encoder[Time] =
    deriveEncoder
  private implicit final val timeOrErrorCirceEncoder: Encoder[Either[Error, Time]] =
    Encoder.either[Error, Time](leftKey = "error", rightKey = "time")
  private implicit final val timeOrErrorEntityEncoder: EntityEncoder[IO, Stream[IO, Either[Error, Time]] =
    streamJsonArrayEncoderOf
  
  /** Returns the service itself. */
  def apply(times: Times)
           (implicit ev1: ContextShift[IO], ev2: Timer[IO]):HttpRoutes[IO] = HttpRoutes.of[IO] {
    Root / "streaming" / city =>
      Ok(Stream.awakeEvery[IO](1.second).evalMap(_ => times.get(city.toUpperCase)))
  }
}
```

Comment: I am sorry that I didn't have time to say thank you! Your code works. I had to add some little details (maybe this will help someone if they read it later): `.evalMap(_ => times.get(city.toUpperCase))` and define implicits ContextShift[IO] and Timer[IO]. Thanks again!